# Viber is not working on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, wine, viber

I am new to Linux and I was intending to totally change my OS environment to Linux distros. I chose Ubuntu and downloaded 22.04: Jammy.
Viber is the main communication channel of my work and I seriously needed it.

I have been trying a few days for it to work on my Ubuntu. Still, no hope.

So, could you please help me with it? I am willing to try any way possible except reinstalling Windows OS on my PC. I just need to make it work.

Thank you so much.

**Things I have Tried**

I have tried installing the "viber-unofficial" one from the snap. The app opens up but when I tried to connect, it just says my phone number will be used as the ID and I got no authentication code and cannot continue at all. I reached out to Viber support and they responded that they have received no authentication code request from my server. However, they said they have reset it for me and try again. I did again and nothing.

I also tried the Image installation (sorry, I don't really know about it in depth)

I also tried installing Viber for Ubuntu from the official Viber website (the .deb). I could install but afterwards, it doesn't even launch the app. I tried it multiple times.

The next workaround, I tried using Wine with the Viber.exe (yes, Viber for Windows) using bottles. Nothing happened. I couldn't even install. My wine version was "wine-6.0.3"

I even been finding many sources and read through many discussions but most of them are at least quite a few years back. Some of the links they provided showed "error 404" and the problem remain unsolved.